# Repeated measures ANOVA, with same subjects under 2 treatments

Tags: repeated-measures

I have a group of 6 animals. 
I took the baseline reading (Time 0), put them under Treatment A, then take readings again at Times 2, 4, 6, and 12 hours.
I rest them for 2 weeks.
Then I took a baseline (time 0), put them under Treatment B, then take readings again at Times 2, 4, 6, 12 hours.
I believe this is a repeated measures ANOVA, with within-subject (as Times- with 5 levels: 0,2,4,6,12 hrs) and between-subject (Treatment A, Treatment B).

My problem is, the subjects in Treatment A and Treatment B are the same subjects.
How do I account for that (as in they are not randomized)?

Right now, I ran the repeated measures MANOVA and ANOVA for time*treatment, time, treatment.
Then I ran paired-t test with bonferroni correction (0.05/4) to test Times 2,4,6,12 with Time 0 (of the same treatment).
And I ran paired-t test to test Treatments (A vs B) across time points (Time 0,2,4,6,12).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it really needs more information for a useful answer, and the OP hasn't been seen for years.